# Expo problem : Unable To close foreground service notification after android app is killed

Tags: expo

I am using `Location.startLocationUpdatesAsync()` to get the location coordinates.

I am also having the `foregroundService` option enabled. I am facing a problem though, which is the following: when I am killing the app and I am at the background, the notification of the foreground service is still alive and I am unable to remove it.

To remove the notification from the foreground i must restart or uninstall the app.

Is there any event that I could be listening for when the app is closed, which will allow me to call the `Location.stopLocationUpdatesAsync()` function so that the foreground service will stop? Or is there any other way to remove the foreground service notification?

Expo SDK that i am using is 39.

Comment: I also faced the same problem. @Alexis_Ni Do you already have a solution for this?

Comment: Unfortunately i haven't found any solution for this...

Answer (score 2):

This is a current bug on the `expo-location` package and a PR was submitted to address it: https://github.com/expo/expo/pull/11775